# How do I check if a certain tag is within content and if so don't access site

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So what I am trying to do is access a site based on input from the user. And if that user inputs values that return no results then the browser shouldn't open. Here is the current code I have.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser

jobsearch = input("What type of job?: ")
location = input("What is your location: ")
url = ("https://ca.indeed.com/jobs?q=" + jobsearch + "&l=" + location)

newurl = url
r = requests.get(newurl)
rcontent = r.content
prettify = BeautifulSoup(rcontent, "html.parser")

def site():

  rcontent = r.content
  no_result = prettify.find("div.no_results")
  if no_result == True:
     pass
     print("nothing")
  else:
     website = webbrowser.open_new(newurl);
     return website

site()
```

Comment: Can you precise your issue ? On my environment it works. I just tested it.

Comment: What is your issue? Please provide a full traceback of any errors.

Comment: @glegoux well it works but say you input something random such "asdas" and location as " asdasd" the original page would say nothing matches and provides a tag "div.no_results" within the content. Now what i am trying to do is say that appears because there are no results for said job, I would like to have the program not open the page but print a text instead.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is HTML encoding, look it up :)